# Chaining Regex replace on apache superset with postgres backend

Tags: postgresql, apache-superset

I am trying to create a new column based on other column with regexp on apache-superset and postgres backend.

I am using:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(website,'^[a-z]{2}\\.google.com', 'google')
```

Which works and now I have a new column where 'google' is present when the regexp is True. How can I chain multiple statements for example have:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(website,'^[a-z]{2}\\.google.com', 'google')
REGEXP_REPLACE(website,'^[a-z]{2}\\.bing.com', 'bing')
```

When I try to add new regexp_replace it stops working, I've tried separating the statements by a comma but it does not work.

Basically I need something similar to this in postgres:

```
CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(website,'^[a-z]{2}\\.google.com')
        THEN 'google'
    WHEN  REGEXP_MATCH(website,'^[a-z]{2}\\.bing.com')
        THEN 'bing'
    ELSE '(other)'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a capture group:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(website,'^[a-z]{2}\\.(google|bing)\\.com', '\\1')
```

Note that if the above does not work, then try using `\1` or `$1` as the capture group.

Comment: So this adds 'google or 'bing' based on which expression is true. I am not sure I understand what does the '\\1'  men. And what if the regex expressions are different, how could I chain them?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis `\1` or `\\1` is the first _capture_ group, which is whatever term appeared in parentheses.  In this case, it would either be `google` or `bing`.

Comment: Thank you, what if, for example I want to chain such regex expressions: `^[a-z]{2}\\.google.com'` and `^{2}\\.bing.com'`? Just different ones and assign different names for each match?

Comment: I think you're missing the point of my answer; it already is doing this `:-)`

Comment: Yes I see, but the start for both expressions are the same - `^[a-z]{2}\\.`. What if I want to check a string with two different expressions and assign a string that would represent if it matched the first expression or the second. For example one starts with `^[a-z]{2}\\.` and another starts with `^[a-z]\\.`?

Comment: You are changing your question now.  Please edit the question and show us the actual problem.